# Any simple way to setup php pecl-svn on MAC OS 10.6 using XAMPP?

Tags: php, svn, xampp, osx-snow-leopard, pecl

I am trying to use svn from php and tried this so far without any success :(

(trying to install [pecl svn](http://pecl.php.net/package/svn) extension)

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install svn
```

I choose autodetect for following:

```
Please provide the prefix of Subversion installation [autodetect] : 
Please provide the prefix of the APR installation used with Subversion [autodetect] :
```

the last output from the command is :

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/svn.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/svn-1.0.2
Extension svn enabled in php.ini
```

server restart and test a simple function give me this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function svn_log()
```

phpinfo does not list the svn extension either and I see following in apache error log :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/svn.so' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/svn.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/svn.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Mac OS 10.6, not Mac OS 6... Or it's just going to be a pain in the ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling I [found this](http://benbuckman.net/tech/12/01/how-install-xhprof-osx-snow-leopard-or-lion-and-xampp) way to resolved this :

1) Downloaded the latest svn pecl extension , unziped to it to svn-1.0.1 and `cd` to svn-1.0.1

2) executed command `sudo phpize`

2) executed : `sudo MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6 CFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' ./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config-5.3.1`

3) `sudo make`

4) `sudo make install`

```
Installing shared extensions:     /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
```

Done !  now it seems svn extension is loaded peacefully

But I still do now know why pecl install command failed to compile it